# Django how urls.py how to add url / problem in adding url

Tags: python, django

i created my first app in Django. and when i am running it in my chrome browser using the url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello
```

It didn't open but when i used the url:-

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

It worked, don't know why. I added the url in urls.py file. like this.

```
path('hello', views.hello_world_view, name='hello')
```

suggest me where i am going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What does your main urls.py look like for your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL patterns require a trailing slash in order to work

```
path('hello/', views.hello_world_view, name='hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

Write like this

```
path('hello/', views.hello_world_view, name='hello')
```

read this [djangoproject for URLs dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example) it will help you how to configure URL into Django